# Boost root directory in homebrew installing

Tags: python, boost, bjam

I installed boost and boost-build through homebrew on OS X. I am trying to run the hello world tutorial, but the include Jamroot.jam has the following line:

```
# Specify the path to the Boost project.  If you move this project,
# adjust this path to refer to the Boost root directory.
use-project boost
  : ../../../.. ;
```

I am not sure what to replace that directory with. I've tried

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.62.0
```

But then I end up with "error: Unable to load Jamfile", when the Jamfile is clearly in the direct where I am running bjam.

I am missing some step here in compiling this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I ended up just installing using the boost source and bjam through there. With the new version of boost, bjam does not require a reference to the python installation so this question is obsolete.